# Pecl can't find zlib while installing pecl_http (Mac OS)

Tags: macos, zlib, pecl

I'm trying to install pecl_http, but it fails and says:

```
...
checking for zlib... no
checking whether zlib version  >= 1.2.0.4... configure: error: no
ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/install/pecl_http/configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/opt/php@8.0/bin/php-config --with-http-zlib-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/zlib/1.2.11/include --with-http-libcurl-dir=/usr --with-http-libevent-dir=/usr --with-http-libicu-dir=/usr --with-http-libidn2-dir=/usr --with-http-libidn-dir=/usr --with-http-libidnkit2-dir=/usr --with-http-libidnkit-dir=/usr' failed
```

Of course I installed zlib via `brew install zlib`

```
Warning: zlib 1.2.11 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 1.2.11, run:
  brew reinstall zlib
```

I also tried:

1. Reinstall php
2. Reinstall zlib
3. `pecl install pecl_http --with-zlib-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/zlib/1.2.11/include`
4. `pecl install pecl_http --with-zlib-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/zlib/1.2.11/include/zlib.h`
5. `pecl install pecl_http` -> `...where to find zlib [/usr] : /usr/local/Cellar/zlib/1.2.11/include...`

I have no more ideas, will be glad to hear yours. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can just give `zlib` folder

For me it was `/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib`.
`brew info zlib` gave me this answer :

```
$ brew info zlib
[...]
For compilers to find zlib you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/include"
[...]
```

See :

```
where to find zlib [/usr] : /opt/homebrew/opt/zlib
```

With :

```
$ ls -al /opt/homebrew/opt/zlib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 guillaume  admin  21 Oct 25 23:07 /opt/homebrew/opt/zlib -> ../Cellar/zlib/1.2.13

$ ls -al /opt/homebrew/Cellar/zlib/1.2.13 
total 200
drwxr-xr-x  10 guillaume  admin    320 Feb 24 16:35 .
drwxr-xr-x   3 guillaume  admin     96 Oct 25 23:07 ..
drwxr-xr-x   3 guillaume  admin     96 Oct 13 07:06 .brew
-rw-r--r--   1 guillaume  admin  82522 Oct 13 07:06 ChangeLog
-rw-r--r--   1 guillaume  admin    975 Feb 24 16:35 INSTALL_RECEIPT.json
-rw-r--r--   1 guillaume  admin   1002 Oct 13 07:06 LICENSE
-rw-r--r--   1 guillaume  admin   5368 Oct 13 07:06 README
drwxr-xr-x   4 guillaume  admin    128 Oct 13 07:06 include
drwxr-xr-x   7 guillaume  admin    224 Oct 25 23:07 lib
drwxr-xr-x   3 guillaume  admin     96 Oct 13 07:06 share
```

Source that helped me : https://github.com/m6w6/ext-http/issues/106